# Catching a crash

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, logs, crash

I am running Fedora 25 on a reasonably recent beefy computer. This is a `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5960X CPU @ 3.00GHz` with 16 cores and 64Gb RAM on kernel `4.8.11-300.fc25.x86_64`. However, every so often when either memory usage rises to more than 20Gb or CPU usage is quite high the computer bricks and I have no idea why.

I would like to understand why this happens and have some logs to find out the issue. How can I setup my computer to understand what is the problem next time it happens. (By the way, `memtestx86+` shows no problem in RAM)

One idea I was would be to ssh into the machine from another terminal and have a `journalctl --follow` command running but I am wondering if there's a better way or another suggestion.

Comment: You might be hitting some thermal trip, eg from bad heatsink conductivity. Check bios settings for cpu throttle enabled, fan speed limits. Your bios may have a log of last machine check. You may see messages on the (non-X11) console. Monitor temperatures with package `lm_sensors`.

Comment: I tend to keep track of the temp. at all times and nothing comes from there. As it happened the CPU started to choke yesterday and I had a terminal with `htop` and I noticed Xorg going up to 100% CPU with compton at 9%. Thinks stopped momentarily and I thought that was it, however a very slow remote login was on time and I killed the process saving myself from a crash.